# VLC keeps freezing on Mac OS X El Capitan

Tags: macos, video, performance, vlc

I have the latest versions for both El Capitan and VLC, however, ever since I've upgraded to El Capitan, VLC keeps freezing during playback. Generally to solve this: I have to pause, exit fullscreen, play and wait for it to start playing again. Every time it plays again, there is a grey overlap that comes over the video (which eventually goes away).

I was thinking that it may be a temporary thing but this has been happening to me quite often now. Is anyone else facing this? Are there any solutions out there?

It shouldn't be anything hardware related. I have a pretty decent configuration for a MacBook Pro NR.

VLC Version: 2.2.1 64-bit
Mac OS X Version: 10.11.3
RAM: 16GB DDR3 1600 MHz
Processor: Intel i5 @ 2.5 GHz

Comment: You do not have the latest version of VLC for OS X, the latest version of VLC for OS X is 2.2.2, so you might want to try it and see if the issue persists.

Comment: @user3439894 that's a common bug in VLC for OS X. When running v2.2.1 and checking for updates, it does not detect anything new.

Comment: This is happening to me with VLC 2.2.4 and OS X 10.11.6 (Mid 2010 Mac Mini).

Comment: @Munkymorgy I finally found out that the real reason this was happening to me was because my hard drive was dying. Other symptoms of this would including frequent system freezes and such. I suggest looking into that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have the latest version of VLC for OS X, at the present time, the latest version of [VLC for OS X is 2.2.2](http://get.videolan.org/vlc/2.2.2/macosx/vlc-2.2.2.dmg), so you might want to try it and see if the issue persists.

In clicking **VLC** > **Check for Update...**, note as shown in the image below it says:

> More than 100 fixes for issues reported for 2.2.1. 
>   Full support of Mac OS X 10.11 El Capitan.

[image]

*Note: If Check for Update... doesn't work then click the link above to download the vlc-2.2.2.dmg file and manually install it after deleting the existing application bundle.*

Comment: Thanks for this. It seems to have fixed the problem for while, but for some random reason, this has started happening again. I am on 2.2.2 this time and there are no updates available (I check on VLC's website too). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if anyone is still having this issue but I just installed the latest version 2.2.4 and it had the same issue on Mac OS Sierra. The fix for me was to download VLC 2.0.10 - www.videolan.org/vlc/download-macosx.html

Answer (score 0):

Installed VLC 2.2.8 and it had the same issue on Mac OS High Sierra 10.13.1. Total freeze of video for 3 seconds while sound keeps playing.
And much worse keyboard and the touchpad are also none responsive. Meaning the whole macbook is frozen for 3 seconds. Can not even adjust the volume!

With x264 encoded videos. Going back to VLC 2.0.10 solves it. But then you can not play any x265 content.